# Case Statement in Select Not Working

Tags: sql-server, case

This is for SQL Server 2012 database...

I'm reading a varchar data column from a table, and depending on user-selected options the data could be either alphanumeric or numeric.  I need to sort by this column so I'm trying to use a case statement, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Below is a simplified example of what I'm doing, but as you can see, it's falling through to the Else of the case statement in both scenarios...any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
Select  '1st Grade Math' topic Into #temp

Declare @rptView int
Set @rptView = 1

Select  Case @rptView 
      When 1 Then topic 
      Else cast(topic as int)
    End 
From    #temp 
Order by Case @rptView 
      When 1 Then topic 
      Else cast(topic as int)
     End 

Select  Case 
      When @rptView = 1 Then topic 
      Else cast(topic as int)
    End 
From    #temp 
Order by Case @rptView 
      When 1 Then topic 
      Else cast(topic as int)
     End 

drop table #temp
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is create a column with both `varchar` and `int` datatypes. This can't be done.

Comment: I think the error speaks for itself Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1st Grade Math' to data type int. -- cast(topic as int)

Comment: Each outcome in a case statement must return the same data type, so as mentioned elsewhere it tries convert the result to a common data type, the one with the highest [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190309.aspx). As you can see, INT is higher than varchar, which is why it tries to output an INT rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example based on your table:

```
 Select Case 1 When 1 Then topic 
                      Else 5
               End 
   From #temp
```

It *also* fails with the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1st Grade Math' to data type int.
```

Why? Because **every expression must have a well-defined data type**. SQL Server deduces that the type of your first column is `int`, since the ELSE clause contains an int. Thus, it tries to convert `topic` to int as well, which fails.

In other words: You can't do it like that. The field in your result set can be varchar *or* int, not both.

Comment: Props to both Heinzi and @Bridge for clearly explaining what I am doing wrong -- VERY much appreciated.  

My assumption was that with the Case statement, it would drop into the proper scenario and follow those instructions without concerning itself with what the other instruction sets were doing, so as long as I stayed consistent with the field type, I could do what I attempted to do.  Oh well, back to the drawing board!!

Comment: May I also ask for some professional courtesy and get an explanation on why this question was voted down?

Comment: @JimmyGenslinger: I thought it was a good question and it includes a great [mcve]! (Shame on me for not upvoting it earlier.) The things I'd improve would be (1) to add the error message into the question itself, so that people don't have to try it to see what is wrong, and (2) to fix the indentation and inconsistent capitalization of the SQL example. Maybe one of those was the reason for the downvote, but I can only speculate.

Answer (score 0):

Adding few more examples which may help..

```
declare @a int=1
declare @b varchar='b'

--this works
select 
case when @a=1 then @a else @b end

--this also works
select 
case when @a=2 then @b  else @b end


--this fails
select 
case when @a=1 then @b else @a end

--this fails
select 
case when @a=2 then @a else @b end
```

Why ..?Because of data type precedence ,SQL tries to convert everything to type with higher precedence